# How to use LocationListener without "implements LocationListener"?

Tags: java, android, implementation

i finally reached an app that get's the GPS position of the user, but i reached it implementing LocationListener. it works fine, but i need to do it without implementing it, because i have to do a class that doesn't implement methods.

I searched for a lot of tutorials and check a lot of websites and i try to transform my code to not implement LocationListener but i can't do it, every thing i tested broken my app and stop getting the GPS position of the user.

Please, if someone expert on this can transform my code for not be using "implements LocationListener" i'll be grated to him

this is the code to transform:

```
public class GpsMiniActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

private LocationManager mLocMgr;
private TextView tv1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout ll= new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(rl);
    rl.addView(ll);

    tv1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    ll.addView(tv1);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            500, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    tv1.setText("Lat " +   location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "because i have to do a class that doesn't implement methods"?

Comment: "because i have to do a class that doesn't implement methods" - that sounds like a pretty useless class to me. If you're going to provide fairly unreasonable requirements, please give more details of *why* you want to go away from the obvious and natural way of doing things.

Comment: Why do you feel you have this requirement around not implementing an interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class GpsMiniActivity extends Activity {

private LocationManager mLocMgr;
private TextView tv1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout ll= new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(rl);
    rl.addView(ll);

    tv1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    ll.addView(tv1);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            500, 0, ll);
}
}
private LocationListener ll = new LocationListener(){
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    tv1.setText("Lat " +   location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
}
```

There you go.

Comment: Do you need to do any cleanup during onDestroy() ?

Answer (score 3):

For that you will have to create a seperate `LocationListener` outside the `onCreate()` and give the reference of it to the LocationManager's `requestLocationUpdates` like this

```
 LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                tv1.setText("Lat " +   location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        };
```

And after that you will have to reference this LocationListener like this inside the `onCreate()`

```
mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                500, 0, mLocationListener);
```